# How i can get text from web element and print in console (for example)

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a problem with getting a text from elements on a web page.
I'm using TestCafe e2e framework and want to print the contents of a text web element to console. Can you provide some code?

```
const getInnerText = ClientFunction(() => homePage.kzLink.innerText);
console.log(getInnerText());
```

what i get:

```
ReExecutablePromise { _then: [], _fn: [Function], _taskPromise: null }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To execute a client function, call it with the await keyword and a dependency.

```
const getInnerText = ClientFunction(() => homePage.kzLink.innerText, { 
    dependencies: { homePage.kzLink }
});

test('My Test', async t => {
    const text = await getInnerText();
    console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: And if you add dependency: const getInnerText = ClientFunction(() => homePage.kzLink.innerText, {
     dependencies: { homePage.kzLink }
});

Comment: If `homePage.kzLink` is a Selector, you could simply do: `console.log(await homePage.kzLink.textContent)`